# Android, how to emulate swipe gestures in AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, swipe-gesture

How do I simulate swipe gestures (left and right, for example) on AVD?
Is it possible at all? (In [Android Developer's Guide - Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)
I can't find them...

P.S.: I do have "Touch-screen support" set to "yes" in my Android 2.2, API level 8 device settings

Comment: Clicking and holding with the mouse pointer doesn't work?

Comment: Ya thats worked for me - click and hold - drag left/right - let go.

Comment: It really doesn't work for me... I'm using a ViewFlipper horizontal layout (on a real device, left/right swipe does work...)

Comment: Don't know if my problems are related to what MarcoS is asking about, but I have had problems with the swipe gesture on the "All Apps" screen on the emulator. I could drag the screen so it was about 70% gone and the second screen with a couple of apps was coming into view (becoming less transparent), but when I released the mouse button the first screen would snap back into place. Again and again. I finally determined that I can usually get it to work by 1. stop moving the mouse when the screen stops moving, and 2. hold the mouse button for about five seconds before releasing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just click and hold and move the mouse to created the desired motion.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... :-( Did you really check it does work for you?

Comment: Yes, I haven't had any trouble with any user input on the emulator.

Comment: Sorry, I had a problem with my software, dragging mouse works great... :-(((

Answer (score 5):

One easier way is recording and playing.

Instead of processing [`getevent`](https://source.android.com/devices/input/getevent)'s command output, then sending your results to  `sendevent` which is really slow. I managed to blindly record the gestures from a real device with the same Android version as my AVD, then streamed the recorded data to the input buffer, this succeeded to fool the device.

You can copy the touch input of a real device by:

1. Using [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) command, in adb shell run `dd if=/dev/input/event2 of=/sdcard/left`. This will buffer all the touch input data to `/sdcard/left` file.
2. Do the gesture you like to simulate (swipe).
3. Now that `(/sdcad/left)` is populated by the data generated by your real touch. You can exit the `dd` command (ctrl + c).
4. Move the file from you real device to any location in your AVD, lets say `(/sdcad/left)`.
5. In AVD adb shell, run `dd if=/sdcard/left of=/dev/input/event2`

Viola! the simulated touch event will happen.

*NOTE: In my device the file which has touch events is `/dev/input/event2` , it might differ from a device to another, so you may use trial and error first.*

---

In short, if you record and play on the same device:

1. `dd if=/dev/input/event2 of=/sdcard/left`
2. Do the touch for real
3. `dd if=/sdcard/left of=/dev/input/event2`
4. Repeat step 3, as much as you need.

Comment: i don't know this will help me???.... but this gave me some idea... thank you omer...+1 to you....

Answer (score 2):

You can record input event and replay them on the emulator, by using the adb shell getevent and adb shel sendevent, a bit hard tounderstand, and requires to translate the hex values of getevent output to decimal, but very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: I think you might feel that it doesn't work when the problem is that it's just really slow bringing the user-input processing online.  If you mess with it for 10 minutes and it still doesn't work, then there's something wrong - but give it the 10 minutes first.

Here's my experience so you can see how I came to that conclusion:

I never explicitly added a device to the AVD Manager - Studio added it for me.

When I ran my (Hello World) app, it took quite a while to come up - first nothing seemed to be happening, so I clicked on "Android" at the bottom of Studio's window and found that it was logging what it was doing.

There were still numerous delays.  A minute or so later, the emulator popped up and it had a message about missing a backup or something like that.  Another minute or so later, I saw that it said "Charging", so I clicked and dragged but nothing happened.  I tried that a few more times and finally it responded by changing "Charging" to "Swipe to unlock" (I think - something like that).  So I tried the click-drag a few more times but it didn't seem to register the drag.  Finally I noticed the camera (software) button light up when I moused over it, so I clicked it, then I got into the camera (not sure if it was by dragging or clicking the little < in the white circle), and from there I could do stuff.